# Issue with Toolbar in CollapsingToolbarlayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I started using a collapsing toolbar in my app. After implementing it the way they did on the Android developers blog, it doesn't seem to be working correctly. I see the overflow and up navigation button, however they don't follow the toolbar when I scroll downwards. This [video](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQscXNQY3dNdVlYeTQ/patterns-scrolling-techniques_flex_space_image_xhdpi_003.webm) is what should be happening, everything works fine except for the fact that the overflow/up navigation icons don't display on the collapsed toolbar.

Projects Detail Activity
package com.austinerck.projectpanda.activity;

```
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.austinerck.projectpanda.R;

public class ProjectDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_project_details);
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_collapse);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Project Name");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_project_details, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_project_details.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_collapse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/error_color"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:text="This text is part of first Cardview\n\n"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/abc_search_url_text"
                        android:text="This text is part of second Cardview\n\n"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using the last version of the Design Support Library? It could be a bug of previous versions

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want your toolbar to move, it should be pinned. The toolbar scroll off can be accomplish with `enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed` on the collapsing toolbar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_collapse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: No that changed the way it handles scrolling. They way I had before was fine. However when I scroll the navigation up and overflow icons don't follow the toolbar, so I can only see them when at the very top of the page. Notice how in the video when they scroll down it collapses into a normal toolbar? Well mine does that, but there is a blank space where the icon should have scrolled down.